# query top seller products in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have two models like this

```
class Product(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order_item(models.Model):
    
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

now i want to query "top 10 most seller products between date x and y" from Order_item. how should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution works for me Perfectly!

```
Product.objects.filter(order_item__date_added__lte=datetime.datetime.today(), order_item__date_added__gt=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).annotate(quantity_sum=Sum('order_item__quantity')).order_by('-quantity_sum')[:8]
```